# Clear contents of column if condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a procedure that checks if rows in column BO are empty, if they are, then clear the contents of the same row in column BQ. For example:

[image]

In this example everything after Test 3 in Column BQ should be blank.  I wrote the following:

```
With calcCalculations

For Each rng In Columns("BO").SpecialCells(xlBlanks)
    rng.Offset(, 3).Value = ""

Next

End With
```

But is not working for me. the procedure runs without bugs but nothing happens. Also the data on column BQ is calculated. In other words, the 0 is a result of a formula on column BQ.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just wrap your current formula for the BQ column in an IF() clause, like:

```
=IF(BO1<>"";{current_formula};"")
```

That means: If adjacent cell in column BO is empty, also show an empty string (otherwise show the formula's result).

If you actually want nothing to appear when the value in *column BQ is zero* (rather than depending on the text in column BO), you have to use something like:

```
=IF({current_formula}<>0;{current_formula};"")
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought of that, it actually saved me a couple of steps.